# Issue with bcrypt, py-bcrypt and django-bcrypt

Tags: python-3.x, django, bcrypt, ubuntu-20.04

i have installed `bcrypt==4.0.1` , `py-bcrypt==0.4` and `django-bcrypt==0.9.2` in my django project virtual env. When am trying to run `createsuperuser` command then its giving me following error

```
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt._bcrypt' has no attribute 'encode_base64'
```

Any idea how can i fix this? I have tried multiple versions of `bcrypt` module but it did not worked

Am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS